# What kind of method to use for communications when planning multilayer flash server

Tags: flash, multithreading, http, multiplayer

im planning to build flash multilayer server ( in c++ or java ) 
im not coming from the flash area . But from what im reading flash does support 
sockets , BUT this is not my case i need to be able to support browser flash games
so it leaves me with port 80 with http .but how can i implement good communication architecture with http  ( rest ? ) that the flash player supports 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash, even from within a browser, does support Socket connections, using the `Socket` class (in AS3) or the `XMLSocket` class (AS2/AS3).

But everything depends on what you're planning to do with the application, and how the networking is going to be used. For a multiplayer game, you'd probably need a push-pull network layer (where both the client and the server can send data to each others at any time). A `Socket` can do that.

Using HTTP would need your client to request data repeatedly to your server, which can be a burden both for maintaining a server-side context (you can't tell when a client is disconnected, and there's a lot of spoofing security issues related to this technique), and for performances, especially if your game is designed to be played in real time.

There is a framework for making AS3/Flex application communicate with a Java server, developed by Adobe : [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: one thing i dont understand  is there any way not to use http 
when im working with browser clients

Comment: Both the Socket and XMLSocket classes use TCP and not HTTP.
Socket is better if you're writing in AS3.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Socket or XMLSocket class, make sure your server has a security policy file available.  Check this SO [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204061/flash-client-xmlsocket-not-connecting-to-server/1204326#1204326) for more info.